# Jenkins AD Fallback user

Tags: jenkins

I have configured AD on my jenkins server.
Everything is working fine, but in case AD server goes down, I wanna have a fallback user.

I know that AD plugin allows you to do that, but I'm confused with part

`Use Jenkins Internal Database` and `select user` this selected user must exist on Jenkins internal DB right?

I have no user create internally, so How can create that user internally? Because I have AD integrated already.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The internal user database means XML files under `$JENKINS_HOME/users`. 
The first time you log in with the fallback user, it will update the XML files.
Before the first login, you cannot use the **Use Jenkins Internal Database** feature.

I discover this behavior reading the source code of the change (full story [here (github page)](https://romainjacquet.github.io/why-jenkins-internal-user-doesnt-work.html)).